# Help with getting data from resized image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing

I'm using an ASP.NET file upload control and then resizing an image and storing the new image in a new Bitmap. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    protected void ResizeImage()
    {
        Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.FileContent);
        //Calculate new image dimensions
        int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
        int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
        int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
        int newWidth = 100;
        int newHeight = newWidth / sngRatio;
        Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

I'm uploading directly to Amazon S3 and I need to pass some data to its upload method. How do I get the following information from my new bitmap that I have been using with the fileupload?:

```
FileUpload1.FileBytes
FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length
```

Do I need to save my new bitmap to a stream so I can get an array of bytes?

Comment: Using the Bitmap constructor will give you extremely poor quality images with lots of artifacts. Also, I hope you're using the using(){} clause around both Bitmap instances, because as-is that code will crash the server at 20-100 requests. I suggest you use [a library designed to do server-safe image resizing](http://imageresizing.net) instead, it's easier than avoiding the [29 pitfalls on your own](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `MemoryStream` and call `Bitmap.Save` to it.

You can then call `MemoryStream.ToArray()`.